Attached Collision Objects missing mesh geometry for collision detection
I'm using the Bullet collision detector in a ROS Noetic planning scene to find nearest distances between the robot and other objects in the scene.
Collision detection works perfectly for objects in the urdf and for regular collision objects, but attached collision objects seem to only collide on a single face of the mesh, despite being visualized correctly. This is clearest when a simple cube is attached:

https://ibb.co/nDPYCpw
Note that the object visualizes correctly, but the collision check only takes one face into account.
Collision checks are done using a LockedPlanningSceneRO retrieved each time a check is performed:
        CollisionNode(int argc, char** argv)
        {
            ...

            // Prepare collision result and request objects
            g_c_req.contacts = true;
            g_c_req.distance = true;
            g_c_req.max_contacts = 1;
            g_c_req.max_contacts_per_pair = 1;
            ...
        }

        void update()
        {
            // Update the planning scene monitor, in case new collision objects have been added
            g_planning_scene_monitor->requestPlanningSceneState();
            
            // Get locked planning scene to ensure scene does not change during update
            planning_scene_monitor::LockedPlanningSceneRO locked_planning_scene(g_planning_scene_monitor);

            // Update the collision result, based on the collision request
            g_c_res.clear();
            locked_planning_scene->checkCollision(g_c_req, g_c_res);
        }

The collision objects are currently being spawned and attached using the planning_scene_diff service:
        void test()
        {
            // Create collision object with mesh from file
            moveit_msgs::CollisionObject mesh_object;
            mesh_object.header.frame_id = "world";
            mesh_object.id = "test_mesh";
            std::string test_mesh_path = "file:///root/catkin_ws/src/morpheus_teleop/meshes/components/collision/block.obj";
            const Eigen::Vector3d scale_eigen(0.1, 0.1, 0.1); // mm/inch
            shapes::Mesh* m = shapes::createMeshFromResource(test_mesh_path, scale_eigen);
            shape_msgs::Mesh mesh;
            shapes::ShapeMsg mesh_msg;
            shapes::constructMsgFromShape(m, mesh_msg);
            mesh = boost::get<shape_msgs::Mesh>(mesh_msg);
            mesh_object.meshes.resize(1);
            mesh_object.meshes[0] = mesh;
            mesh_object.pose.position.x = 0.3;
            mesh_object.pose.position.y = 0.35;
            mesh_object.pose.position.z = 0.8;
            mesh_object.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
            mesh_object.operation = mesh_object.ADD;
            moveit_msgs::AttachedCollisionObject mesh_attach;
            mesh_attach.object = mesh_object;
            mesh_attach.link_name = "wrist_3_link";
            
            // Create planning scene diff for spawning
            moveit_msgs::PlanningScene planning_scene;
            planning_scene.world.collision_objects.push_back(mesh_object);
            planning_scene.is_diff = true;
            planning_scene.robot_state.is_diff = true;

            // Publish planning scene diff for spawning
            ROS_INFO_STREAM("Spawning object");
            try {
                ros::ServiceClient planning_scene_diff_client = nh.serviceClient<moveit_msgs::ApplyPlanningScene>("apply_planning_scene");
                planning_scene_diff_client.waitForExistence();
                moveit_msgs::ApplyPlanningScene srv;
                srv.request.scene = planning_scene;
                planning_scene_diff_client.call(srv);
                ROS_INFO_STREAM("Spawn succeeded");
            } catch (...) {
                ROS_INFO_STREAM("Spawn failed");
            }
            
            // Create planning scene diff for attaching
            moveit_msgs::PlanningScene planning_scene_attach;
            planning_scene_attach.robot_state.attached_collision_objects.push_back(mesh_attach);
            planning_scene_attach.is_diff = true;
            planning_scene_attach.robot_state.is_diff = true;
            
            // Publish planning scene diff for attaching
            ROS_INFO_STREAM("Attaching object");
            try {
                ros::ServiceClient planning_scene_diff_client = nh.serviceClient<moveit_msgs::ApplyPlanningScene>("apply_planning_scene");
                planning_scene_diff_client.waitForExistence();
                moveit_msgs::ApplyPlanningScene srv;
                srv.request.scene = planning_scene_attach;
                planning_scene_diff_client.call(srv);

                ROS_INFO_STREAM("Attach succeeded");
            } catch (...) {
                ROS_INFO_STREAM("Attach failed");
            }
        }

A non-exhaustive list of other methods tried:

Publishing a moveit_msgs/PlanningScene to /move_group/monitored_planning_scene and/or /planning_scene topics,
Publishing moveit_msgs/CollisionObject and moveit_msgs/AttachedCollisionObject to their respective topics,
Using PlanningSceneInterface.applyPlanningScene()
Using shared_ptr->newPlanningSceneMessage()
Using LockedPlanningSceneRW->usePlanningSceneMessage()

None of the above fix the issue, and applying to exclusively the local planning scene interface or planning scene without publishing results in additional issues.
Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks in advance.
